# CSS Rule exclude parent class

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I write a CSS Rule that selects all `div.box` that are **not** inside `.container`?

The following snippet is not working because there is a `div` without `.container` inside the `div.container`.

```css
div:not(.container) .box {
   background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">box</div> <!-- select this -->
<div class="container">
    <div>txt</div>
    <div><div class="box">box</div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">box</div> <!-- select this -->
```

Comment: In that case I believe you'll have to override the style. Like `.container .box {background:initial}`

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to override every attribute, the only way I see is to give an additional class to the boxes inside of the specific container.

```css
.box:not(.exclude) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">box</div> <!-- select this -->
<div class="container">
    <div>txt</div>
    <div><div class="box exclude">box</div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">box</div> <!-- select this -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In a way, the CSS rule you are asking for is sort of backwards. You should start with the most generic rules, and then add more specific ones. In your case, you should do something like the following:

```css
/* Generic Box styles */
.box
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* Boxes in a container */
.container .box
{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Generic Box</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">I'm in a container</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know, but in my case (which is a bit more complex) that produces a lot of exclude CSS selectors. So i wanted to make it more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Select all `div.box` or all `div` not inside `.container`?  What you ask for and what you say you want selected in the html code sample are not the same thing.  That said, your css selectors are just out of order.  Try:

```
div.box:not(.container) {
   background:red;
}
```

and

```
<div class="box">box</div>
<div class="container">
    <div>txt</div>
    <div><div class="box">box</div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">box</div>
```

If you want all the divs, just remove the `.box`